# Change language in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to implement language changing buttons in my CakePHP app. I followed the cookbook (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) and now I am able to change language after the user is logged in.

My language buttons are linked to actions in my own `LanguagesController` that looks like this:

```
public function sk() {
    $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'svk');
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}

public function en() {
    $this->Session->write('Config.language', 'eng');
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

And then in `AppController beforeFilter()` function I have following:

```
if ($this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
}
```

However, this only works when the user is logged, and I want to let the not logged users to change the application language too. I tried this:

```
public function en() {
    Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

but it didn't work for me.

Another thing - I want to change the default language for the app to Slovak, but when I put:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'svk');
```

to the `app/Config/bootstrap.php` none of the mentioned above worked at all.

Thanks for your help guys in advance :)

Comment: In App controller you will get  this line `$this->Auth->allow()` somewhere. in that just give those action names which are going to change  language . that functions starts working without user login also. please try once.

Comment: @MarekGalinski just take note that adding `$this->Auth->allow()` to your `AppController::beforeFilter` will allow any page to be accessed.  I recommend you should rather add it to your Languages controller instead.

Comment: Also note, that slovak locale code should be **'slk'** (ISO 639-2, from version 2.3).

Comment: It not that I allowed all, i just added 'sk' and 'en' (my own actions in the LanguagesController) so i guess it's safe.

Comment: @MarekGalinski please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake php proivide a very nice way to execute function without being login into the system. that is `$this->Auth->allow()` in `AppController`.

So

In App controller you will get this line `$this->Auth->allow()` somewhere. in that just give those action names which are going to change language . that functions starts working without user login also. If you didn't find this line in your `AppController` then you can write it also .

Comment: Be careful when adding `$this->Auth->allow()` to your `AppController::beforeFitler()` as it will make everything public.  Rather use it in individual controllers and in a conditional if you only want specific actions to be accessed.  Read more about it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public).

Comment: I didn't say that use it in `AppController::beforeFitler()`. you only assumed it. thanks

Comment: `App Controller` looks a lot like `AppController` so it's worthwhile mentioning  in case someone comes along and interprets it differently.